# How can I center a header, 4 boxes, and 4 text items within a single Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

```
/* stylesheet */

.container {
    display: flex;
    border: solid;
    border-color: blue;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 500px;
    flex-direction: column;
    
       
}

.block {
    border: solid;
    border-color: mistyrose;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.block1 {background-color: olive;}
.block2 {background-color: orangered;}
.block3 {background-color: palegreen;}
.block4 {background-color: royalblue;}

.head {
   border: solid;
   border-color: mistyrose;
}

.text {
   border: solid;
   border-color: mistyrose;
}
```

I am having a hard time grasping Flexbox. It's more guesswork than actually knowing what I am doing. CSS-tricks.com's cheatsheet and Flexbox Froggy are not helping me understand.

**I want to center a header above 4 boxes and under the boxes are 4 text items.** The boxes and text items are **centered on the cross axis**, but **spaced-around on the main axis**. If I put flex-direction: column, I can get them stacked properly on top of each other, but then I can't separate the boxes and then. I tried align-self on the boxes and text, no go. I have tried flex-wrap so many times with different height combos and I can't ever get it to work properly. I don't know if I need flexboxes inside flexboxes, or I need to play with margins? So lost...

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/ct2k/pen/JjrwaKx

Comment: yes, you can use flexboxes inside flexboxes, Its not a bad practice.

Comment: https://codepen.io/kazmi066/pen/QWqzVgq

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```css
/* stylesheet */

.container {
    display: flex;
    border: solid;
    border-color: blue;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 500px;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.block {
    border: solid;
    border-color: mistyrose;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 48px;
    text-align: center;
}

.block1 {background-color: olive;}
.block2 {background-color: orangered;}
.block3 {background-color: palegreen;}
.block4 {background-color: royalblue;}

.head {
   border: solid;
   border-color: mistyrose;
}

.text {
   border: solid;
   border-color: mistyrose;
   width:25%;
  text-align:center
}

.flex1{
  display: flex;
  width:400px
}

.flex2{
  padding-top: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  width:400px;
  align-item:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="head">Head</h2>
  <div class="flex1">
    <div class="block block1">1</div>
    <div class="block block2">2</div>
    <div class="block block3">3</div>
    <div class="block block4">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex2">
    <div class="text">text text1</div>
    <div class="text">text text2</div>
    <div class="text">text text3</div>
    <div class="text">text text4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```